# Filter WFFM report by date range

Tags: wffm

Is it possible to filter WFFM reports by date range in Sitecore v8.2 ?

Current reports are either taking a long time to run or are timing out.

Users have requested the ability to add a date filter to limit the number of records being returned and to reduce the wait time for reports to be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason for slow response or timeout of the WFFM reports are db indexes.

Could you please try the following on WFFM database of your instance:

1) add an additional index for the FormId to the FieldData table:

```
USE [Sitecore_Wffm]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FormId_FieldData]
ON [dbo].[FieldData] ([FormId])
GO
```

2) Rebuild both [PK_FieldData] and [PK_FormData] 
3) Make sure that Avg. Fragmentation is within 5% for all indexes.

To check the Avg. Fragmentation, you can use the "Index Physical Statistics" from Standard Report.

[image]

[image]

Once the Avg. Fragmentation is within 5%, try to generate the reports again which should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am currently looking at rebuilding the indexes but specifically wanted to find a way to restrict wffm reports by date.

Comment: You can look at the https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11615/add-new-export-button-in-wffm-3-4. This is not exactly what you need but it gives an idea from where you can start working to get the date filter functionality. Reg indexes, if it improves the performance of the reporting then do update the status as it could help others.

Comment: I hadn't thought of taking that approach. Thanks!